# Can I use FakeItEasy to fake Properties.Settings.Default properties?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, stub, fakeiteasy

I am trying to do something similar to `A.CallTo(() => MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.SomeProperty).Returns("Hello, World! ;-)");`, but I do get…

> Non virtual methods can not be intercepted.

… in return.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FakeItEasy can not be used to override `SomeProperty`. The problems is that `Default` is a member of type `Settings` which is a `sealed` class. In order to be able to use `A.CallTo` with `Default.SomeProperty`, `Default` must be a fake object created using [A.Fake<…>](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating-fakes/).

Also, `SomeProperty` will need to be virtual or otherwise overridden, as shown in the documentation's [What can be faked](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/) page.

If you need to be able to provide fake configuration in your tests, you could introduce a layer of abstraction around the configuration and fake that, with your production code using a concrete class that delegates to `MyProject.Properties.Settings`…

An alternative (which I think is superior) is to avoid faking/mocking altogether and just change the settings directly, perhaps by doing something like this:

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.SomeProperty= "Hello, World! ;-)"
```

Although as pointed out in the comments, this is only an option if the property has a setter, which it seems that Application properties do not, but User properties do.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think you're missing some code in your last line?

Comment: Thanks, @exalted. I'm easily distracted. Forgot the "modify" part of copy/paste/modify…

Comment: Thanks Blair, that makes a lot of sense! ;-)

Comment: Okay, that was too quick. Unfortunately `SomeProperty` doesn't have a setter. ;-(

Comment: Ah. I had never used project settings before I read your question. When I added them to a project I had lying around, I must have created a "User" property, which has a setter. Yours is an "Application" setting? In that case, if you can't just change the initial value (because you want to test with different values), I'd recommend adding a layer of abstraction.